# Django POST violates not-null constraint user_id

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

Having trouble finding the answer to my question even on here. I know there are posts like it but I am still not getting it.

I get the error when trying to POST to my "user_profile" Below is the error and my code.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
```

models.py which has a foriegnkey from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField
    last_active_date = models.DateTimeField
    alias_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import UserProfile

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    orientation = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)

    def create(self, validated_data):

        return UserProfile.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

userprofile.py the get works fine but the post through the "violates not-null constraint"

```
@csrf_exempt
def user_profile_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        orientation = UserProfile.objects.all().values()
        list2 = list(orientation)
        return JsonResponse(list2, safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Comment: What `data` are you sending in the POST request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have read_only=True so id is not available in POST in UserProfileSerializer.
Model serializer will help you. [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

Comment: awesome, that worked. But now I am getting an error for id

"id":["This field is required."]